# Copy conditional formatting to other columns on a spreadsheet that are not grouped together

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have created conditional formatting in a date column to show red if it's expired, orange if it's 30 days out from expiring.   My boss now wants me to apply this to every register/database that exists.  Problem is that some of the worksheets have multiple date columns and are not one after the other.

I haven't worked out how to copy and/or past the conditional formatting to the other date columns on the worksheets without redoing the conditional formatting from scratch.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is for Excel and you are dealing with entire columns then I suggest starting again (so we know what formulae are in use and that the Applies to range is a complete column) with, say for ColumnA, HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(A1<>"",A1<TODAY()+30)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select orange, OK, OK.

Then repeat for red with:

```
=AND(A1<>"",A1<TODAY())
```

If these suit for ColumnA you should then be able to pick any one of the conditionally formatted cells, click Format Painter then, select whichever other columns you wish the rules to apply to.

Note that the order in which these rules are applied is significant. In Conditional Formatting Rules Manager red should be above orange (their order may be changed with the up/down arrows) and I'd suggest for red checking `Stop If True`).